# google play registration with pioneer card

Tags: android, google-play, mastercard

I'm new in android's world now I'm developing mobile applications and I want to put them in the play store of google my question is can I have a membership in google play with my pioneer card or I must use a paypal card to do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related with software development